# C# htmlAgilityPack как получить строку в теге strong

Tags: c#, xpath, htmlagilitypack

У меня есть такой xPath локатор

```
"//*[@id='contact_methods']/li[2]/div/strong"
```

который указывает на тег `<strong>`, мне нужно получить текст

Моя попытка :

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
        htmldoc = web.Load(Url);
        HtmlNodeCollection AllNodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='lheight22 margintop5']/a");
        foreach (var el in AllNodes)
        {
            Href = el.GetAttributeValue("href","not found");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Href);
            element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#contact_methods > li:nth-child(2) > div > strong"));
            element.Click();
            var NumberElements = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='contact_methods']/li[2]/div/strong");
            NumberPhone = NumberElements.FirstChild.InnerText.Trim();
            MessageBox.Show(NumberPhone);
        }
```

Все работает вплоть до строки

`NumberPhone = NumberElements.FirstChild.InnerText.Trim();`

В чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Покажите HTML с которым можно будет все это проверить!

Comment: div class="contact-button link {'MyClass'} atClickTracking contact-a" data-rel="phone">
   <i data-icon="phone"></i>
       <strong class="xx-large"> String</strong>

Comment: Добавлять такое стоит в вопрос (кнопка "править" под ним). И это не весь HTML. Давайте с самого начала, весь блок, начиная с `@class='lheight22 margintop5'`.

Comment: код слишком большой, проблема скорее всего не в локаторе, в браузере прекрасно находит этот локатор, скорее всего в преобразовании в тест, или неправильном парсинге содержимого тега

Comment: Любой код можно сократить. Ну а так, мне вам нечем помочь без данных, вы даже не пишете что за проблема у вас возникает на указанной строке. Предполагаю, что `NumberElements.FirstChild` у вас NULL, а значит ваш `//*[@id='contact_methods']/li[2]/div/strong` может быть не правильным (не удивлен), либо в нем нету `Child` элемента. Также лично мне очень сильно не нравится `element.Click();`. ибо если вы делаете "клики" по кнопкам и получаете данные, то они скорей всего сайтом получаются извне, при помощи API, с которым вам скорей всего и надо работать. Сейчас вы делаете непонятные костыли.

Comment: Я скопириовал ваш код, но не могу запустить. Вы же свой код запустить можете. То есть я должен настолько быть хорош, чтобы понять по неработающему для меня коду, не зная даже структуры HTML, по которму вы ищете, вашк проблему и подсказать решение. :)

Comment: цельного html к сожалению нет. а по сему лишь предположение: судя по небольшому куску html, который вы предоставили, у элемента strong нет child'ов, а вы обращаетесь к FirstChild...